# How can i compress (7z) multiple files in one click/command

Tags: windows, command-line, compression, 7-zip, archiving

I have a folder filled with documents i would like a 7z for each document separately.

There are over 800 files.

I'm using windows 10 and specifically want the archive in 7z format.

I've highlighted all of the files inside a folder, and right-clicked. This only seems to give me an option to create one big 7z 'files.7z', but i want file1.7z, file2.7z etc etc, to appear inside the same folder where the documents are (ie. c:/files/)

The only way i can do this is right-click each and every file one-by-one and then the context menu gives me the result i want.

Any help on a better way would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: easiest way would be to loop through the files with the `for` command in conjunction with 7zip's command line options

Comment: i have never used command line since the days of dos when i used to struggle to load a game lol. do you know of any guide for doing this kind of thing specifically?

Comment: because i understand exactly what you mean by iterating with a for loop if i was  using c# in unity lol  but not in command line / powershell or whatever i would need to use for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just the files in one folder, you'll probably want to loop through them in conjunction with 7zip's options.

Batch solution will look like this:

```
for %%A in (C:\Your\Folder\*) do (
    7z <commands> %%A <switches>
)
```

CMD solution will look like this:

```
for %A in (C:\Your\Folder\*) do (7z <commands> %A <switches>)
```

There may also be a way to do this built into 7zip if you [check out the commands/syntax/switches](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/index.htm).

Reference: [7zip Command Line](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/syntax.htm), [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

Comment: thank you. I will try to make a batch file. It's just another rabbithole i'm getting my brain into :D

Comment: it's no problem; good luck and have fun!

Comment: could i quickly ask, why is the '%%' in the batch, and '%' in CMD?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this on runing from "zip.bat", I found it somewhere else and adapted for the same purpose that you are searching for.
It will recourse ALL subdirectories and zip every file individually, leaving the zipped files on their origin subdirectories.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /R %%G IN (*.*) DO (
ECHO "%%G" | FIND /I "zip.bat" 1>NUL) || (
"c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -y -t7z -mmt4 -mx8 "%%~dpnG.zip" "%%G"
REM ___________________________________________________________________
REM This line does the same than above but also deletes original files
REM "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -y -t7z -mmt4 -mx8 "%%~dpnG.zip" "%%G" -sdel
REM ___________________________________________________________________
)
)
```